# Is \d equal to [0-9] in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

```
7
00:00:30,008 --> 00:00:30,066
by line
8
00:00:31,038 --> 00:00:34,050
or later in the nineteen seventies it was usually a
9
00:00:34,005 --> 00:00:38,634^M
video consul but the council was not capable of displaying arbitrate graphics
10
```

The above lines is in a file named 2.txt. I wanna the lines which doesn't start with number. In practice, `sed -i '/^[0-9]+/d' 2.txt` works good. However, `sed -i '/^\d+/d' 2.txt` doesnot. The \d shouldn't be equal to [0-9] in regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Sed does not use Perl-compatible regexes. Regular expression support for GNU tools  is documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes

`\d` is the character <kbd>d</kbd>.

You can use `[[:digit:]]` but not `\d`